# Abort compilation if one of the features is not selected

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, cargo-features

I'm trying to implement a choice option inside Cargo.toml. The idea is that I have 'platforms' - i.e chips that my code runs on. At any given moment, only one of the platforms must be selected, selecting both or selecting neither is not allowed and should abort the compilation as soon as possible.

I created a feature for each platform. Selecting the feature activates the required features inside the hardware support dependencies, pulling the right definitions for my chip, i.e:

```
[features]
platform-nrf52840 = [
  "embassy-nrf/nrf52840",
  "nrf-softdevice/nrf52840"
  ...
]

platform-nrf52832 = [
  "embassy-nrf/nrf52832",
  "nrf-softdevice/nrf52832",
  ...
]
```

It works when I select the right platform (i.e `cargo build --features platform-nrf52840`), but I would like to enforce that one and only one of supported platforms must be supplied at any given time.

I know that this was discussed before as missing feature of Cargo but I wonder if there are workarounds.

So far I tried adding the following guard inside build.rs:

```
#[cfg(not(any(feature = "platform-nrf52832", feature = "platform-nrf52840")))]
compile_error! {
    "You need to select precisely one of the supported platforms.

    Most likely you need to run `cargo build` with --features flag, i.e:
        `cargo build --features platform-nrf52832`

    See Cargo.toml a the list of supported platforms"
}
```

The problem with that approach is that AFAIK build.rs is only used when compiling my own project. Crates that are built before start compiling without the correct features enabled, leading to compilation errors.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but wouldn´t using *crates* be a better solution than using *features* in this scenario ? What if you had 3 crates: **myproject-base**, **myproject-platforma**, **myproject-platformb**. The *a* & *b* crates would both have the *base* crate as a dependency. Either of them could have a bunch more dependencies which relate to that platform. Downstream users would depend on either your A or B crate. This way, the "decision" is settled by the time cargo sorts out the dependency graph, prior to having to do any compilation.

Comment: You can make platform-specific dependencies: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#platform-specific-dependencies Otherwise, if you need to interleave platform-agnostic code and platform-specific code, you can use `cfg` attributes. If this is not what you mean by "platform", please clarify that in your question.

Comment: build.rs is built always, even when your crate is a dependency of someone else. But why not put this `compile_error!()` inside the crate itself, the conventional approach?

Comment: The issue is that typically Cargo compiles the project with multiple workers (i.e -j4), so in my case the project starts compiling together with a couple of crates. So even though the compilation of my project fails because of the guard, other crates continue compiling as background jobs, leading to more error messages that silent my guard. Compiling with `cargo build -j1` helps ensure that the compilation stops precisely if my project fails to compile. I now see that build.rs is a pretty poor way to ensure project-wide configuration - but I have no idea if there are any tools that can help

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I tried both approaches, but I don't think it makes a difference in that case

Comment: I don't understand, why does it matter that dependencies are built before erroring if compilation fails anyway?

Comment: I would like for the user to see a banner with clear instructions on how to configure the project rather than a bunch of unreadable errors. I agree that it's not a big issue but rather a chore - and I can always send users to RTFM.